# Can you share authors (papers) that give a percentage of active and passive vocabulary?

Tags: reference-request

I’m looking for a scholarly source that gives an approximate ratio of speakers' active vs. passive vocabularies.

---

<sup>Where, roughly speaking, *active vocabulary* relates to the vocabulary a speaker uses and *passive vocabulary* to the vocabulary they understand.</sup>

Comment: If you’ve studied psycholinguistics or language acquisition (specifically the mental lexicon) you’d know what I’m talking about.

Comment: Ohh, as in the vocabulary that a person _uses_ vs _understands_? Apologies, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Which language? These stats will vary considerably.

Comment: @curiousdannii, any language as long as it’s a reliable source. It seems you know authors that give accounts of different percentages for different languages, can you share these authors/paper’s names, please?

Comment: I don't know any research, I'm just assuming, as I would for most questions, that things will vary considerably. Don't assume anything is universal in linguistics!

Comment: @curiousdannii this post isn’t related to syntax. It’s related to psycholinguistics, neurolinguistics, LA, etc.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: Does it matter whether the percentages are accurate or not? Lots of educational sources will happily use scores on standardized tests of one sort or another to calculate (their version) of active and passive vocabulary according to whatever theory they're following. These are scholarly, for a certain definition of that phrase, but they are unlikely to give useful information out of context.

Comment: @jlawler it doesn’t. Could you please share these sources, so that I can read them?